# How to convert an WAV audio file into Core Audio File Format (CAFF), mono, 16-bit @ 44,1 kHz?

Tags: audio, conversion, logic-studio

How to convert an WAV audio file into Core Audio File Format (CAFF), mono, 16-bit @ 44,1 kHz ?

The files I need have a *.caf ending. I need this exact file format to play them on in my iPhone app.

I have Logic Pro 9 (Logic Studio) and Soundtrack Pro 3 installed, but I'm a total sound noob ;)

Can you explain the steps to convert this?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but I bet you can [play these files with VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/).  If VLC can play them, then VLC can convert them.  Just download the program and run it.  Do an advanced open and for output, choose a WAV file.